# Trouble mirroring a normal map from multires modifier to the other side of the character

Tags: normal-map, multiresolution

Hi all i'm having real problems understanding how to mirror my normal map to the other side of my model,
I've tried flipping the normals, copying the uvs to the mirrored side and copying the model and cutting away the other side while trying to join them... am out of ideas and cant quite understand what to do next

Could anyone help walk me through how to take an object with multi res and turn into double sided low res model with displacement maps. its my first time using multi res for sculpting and making normal maps from it (blender 2.83)

with thanks

[[image: Low poly with normal applied][1]]

[image: Backing Normal map]

[image: High res multi resolution sculpt]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: if mirror model is applied before baking it does this error]

Comment: Did you change the "Color Space" to "Non-Color" on the normal map's texture node?

Comment: Yes- as non color data.

Comment: I also removed all modifiers including the mirror as it wouldn't bake with it attached.

Comment: but im not sure if I should apply mirror or remove it, - it would e useful to have a checklist of steps of how to put displacement map on low res mirrored  model
to know what I have missed...

Comment: if applied the mirror model has an error...and the displacement maps on the other side behave strangely as pictured